# How to Throttle all outgoing asynchronous calls to HttpClient across multiple threads in .net Core API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, semaphore, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm designing a .net core web api that consumes an external api that I do not control.  I've found some excellent answers on stack overflow that allowed me to throttle my requests to this external API while in the same thread using semaphoreslim.  I'm wondering how best to extend this throttling to be application wide instead of just throttling for a specific list of Tasks.  I've been learning about HttpMessageHandlers and this seems to be a possible way to intercept all outgoing messages and apply throttling.  But I'm concerned about thread safety and locking issues I may not understand.  I'm including my current throttling code and hope that may be helpful in understanding what I'm trying to do, but across multiple threads, and with tasks being continuously added instead of a pre-defined list of tasks.

```
private static async Task<List<iMISPagedResultResponse>> GetAsyncThrottled(List<int> pages, int throttle, IiMISClient client, string url, int limit)
{
        var rtn = new List<PagedResultResponse>();
        var allTasks = new List<Task>();
        var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: throttle);
        foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            await throttler.WaitAsync();
            allTasks.Add(
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await GetPagedResult(client, url, page);
                        return result;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        throttler.Release();
                    }
                }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
        foreach (var task in allTasks)
        {
            var result = ((Task<PagedResultResponse>)task).Result;
            rtn.Add(result);
        }
        return rtn;
}
```

Comment: You can create a wrapper class around your HttpClient and register it in singleton-scope. Then inside, you'd use something like `Queue<T>`. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/consuming-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern#asyncproducerconsumercollection. Also, while in the context of a background service, this might be of interest too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#queued-background-tasks

Comment: Using `HttpClient` as a singleton is problematic in that it [does not honour DNS updates](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html).  HttpClientFactory is worth using as it manages the `HttpClient` lifetime issues for you.

Comment: Added an additional section to my answer, on starting `Task`s

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Conceptual questions

- `SemaphoreSlim` is thread-safe so there are no thread-safety or locking concerns about using it as a parallelism throttle across multiple threads.
- `HttpMessageHandler`s are indeed an [outbound middleware mechanism to intercept calls placed through `HttpClient`](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers). So they are an ideal way to apply parallelism-throttling to Http calls using `SemaphoreSlim`.

### Simple implementation

So a `ThrottlingDelegatingHandler` might look like this:

```
public class ThrottlingDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _throttler;

    public ThrottlingDelegatingHandler(SemaphoreSlim throttler)
    {
        _throttler = throttler ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(throttler));
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));

        await _throttler.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            _throttler.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Create and maintain an instance as a singleton:

```
int maxParallelism = 10;
var throttle = new ThrottlingDelegatingHandler(new SemaphoreSlim(maxParallelism));
```

Apply that `DelegatingHandler` to all instances of `HttpClient` through which you want to parallel-throttle calls:

```
HttpClient throttledClient = new HttpClient(throttle);
```

That `HttpClient` does not need to be a singleton: only the `throttle` instance does.

I've omitted the Dot Net Core DI code for brevity, but you would register the singleton `ThrottlingDelegatingHandler` instance with .Net Core's container, obtain that singleton by DI at point-of-use, and use it in `HttpClient`s you construct as shown above.

But:

### Better implementation: Using HttpClientFactory (.NET Core 2.1+)

The above still begs the question how you are going to manage `HttpClient` lifetimes:

- Singleton (app-scoped) `HttpClient`s [do not pick up DNS updates](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html). Your app will be ignorant of DNS updates unless you kill and restart it (perhaps undesirable).
- A frequently-create-and-dispose pattern, `using (HttpClient client = ) { }`, on the other hand, [can cause socket exhaustion](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

One of the design goals of `HttpClientFactory` was to manage the lifecycles of `HttpClient` instances and their delegating handlers, to avoid these problems.

In .NET Core 2.1, you could use `HttpClientFactory` to wire it all up in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in the `Startup` class, like this:

```
int maxParallelism = 10;
services.AddSingleton<ThrottlingDelegatingHandler>(new ThrottlingDelegatingHandler(new SemaphoreSlim(maxParallelism)));

services.AddHttpClient("MyThrottledClient")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<ThrottlingDelegatingHandler>();
```

("MyThrottledClient" here is a [named-client approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#named-clients) just to keep this example short; [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typed-clients) avoid string-naming.)

At point-of-use, obtain an `IHttpClientFactory` by DI ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#named-clients)), then call

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("MyThrottledClient");
```

to obtain an `HttpClient` instance pre-configured with the singleton `ThrottlingDelegatingHandler`.

All calls through an `HttpClient` instance obtained in this manner will be throttled (in common, across the app) to the originally configured `int maxParallelism`.

And HttpClientFactory magically deals with all the `HttpClient` lifetime issues.

### Even better implementation: Using Polly with IHttpClientFactory to get all this 'out-of-the-box'

Polly is [deeply integrated with IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-polly-based-handlers) and Polly also provides [Bulkhead policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead) which [works as a parallelism throttle by an identical SemaphoreSlim mechanism](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/8570720145a1846f89ad011fe2df3a132abe1b63/src/Polly.Shared/Bulkhead/BulkheadEngineAsync.cs).

So, as an alternative to hand-rolling a `ThrottlingDelegatingHandler`, you can also just use Polly Bulkhead policy with IHttpClientFactory out of the box.  In your `Startup` class, simply:

```
int maxParallelism = 10;
var throttler = Policy.BulkheadAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(maxParallelism, Int32.MaxValue);

services.AddHttpClient("MyThrottledClient")
    .AddPolicyHandler(throttler);
```

Obtain the pre-configured `HttpClient` instance from HttpClientFactory as earlier.  As before, all calls through such a "MyThrottledClient" `HttpClient` instance will be parallel-throttled to the configured `maxParallelism`.

The Polly Bulkhead policy additionally offers the ability to configure how many operations you want to allow simultaneously to 'queue' for an execution slot in the main semaphore.  So, for instance:

```
var throttler = Policy.BulkheadAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10, 100);
```

when configured as above into an `HttpClient`, would allow 10 parallel http calls, and up to 100 http calls to 'queue' for an execution slot.  This can offer extra resilience for high-throughput systems by preventing a faulting downstream system causing an excessive resource bulge of queuing calls upstream.

To use the Polly options with HttpClientFactory, pull in the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly) and [`Polly`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly) nuget packages.

References: [Polly deep doco on Polly and IHttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory); [Bulkhead policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Bulkhead).

---

### Addendum re Tasks

The question uses `Task.Run(...)` and mentions :

> a .net core web api that consumes an external api

and:

> with tasks being continuously added instead of a pre-defined list of tasks.

If your .net core web api only consumes the external API *once* per request the .net core web api handles, and you adopt the approaches discussed in the rest of this answer, offloading the downstream external http call to a new `Task` with `Task.Run(...)` will be unnecessary and only create overhead in additional `Task` instances and thread-switching. Dot net core will already be running the incoming requests on multiple threads on the thread pool.

Comment: This is a fantastic response - thank you! Only 14 upvotes? Shame

Comment: Assigning that ThrottlingDelegatingHandler to HttpClient just causes everything to fail and tons of errors to be displayed in the VS debugger like this:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Great answer. Seeing @JeffreyLeCours comment, I immediately upvoted. It now stands at 29.

Comment: Great answer, was exactly what i needed. Thanks for that

Comment: Just be aware that with either approach, "artisan" (handcrafted) or polly, I see a problem of `TaskCanceledException`s for the throttled threads. This is because `HttpClient.SendAsync()` uses `cancellationToken` to [honor  `HttpClient.Timeout`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e7b9db69533dca155a33f96523875e9c50445f44/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L381-L392]) and the cts is set _before_ the DHs are executed. To repro `TaskCanceledException`s, add a `DelayDelegatingHandler` in httpClient pipeline to delay for timespan more than the `HttpClient.Timeout` value.

Comment: @hIpPy can you provide example for you thought?

Comment: @Dzendo Here goes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HuTS6M. In fact, I use this trick to _cause_ `TaskCanceledExceptions`s to test out how my code behaves in such cases.

Comment: @hIpPy Thank you. Is there a way to prevent it receiving TaskCanceledExceptions? In fact source system replays below HttpClient.Timeout. Due to heavy thread load i am receiving TaskCanceledExceptions.

Comment: @Dzendo, I don't believe it is possible to honor all requests without a change in design. It cannot be done in the httpClient pipeline i.e. within `httpClient.sendAsync()` as it's too late. Even with a bulkhead polly policy, it will throw on requests once the threshold is reached. You could scale horizontally, or put a queue in between and drain it at a slower rate compared to ingress. (I'm leaving this link as I put the DH code on my github: https://github.com/rmandvikar/delegating-handlers/blob/e77b66afc5a74bae1663e13308ed31cb833557fd/src/rm.DelegatingHandlers/ProcrastinatingHandler.cs)